# send_data - open file in new browser window?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
#in my controller (works just fine)

    order = Order.find(params[:id])
    url = order.receipt.file.url
    data = open(url).read
    send_data(data, type: 'application/pdf', filename: "appname-receipt#{order.id}", disposition: 'inline')
```

This takes a PDF stored in S3, and renders it just fine in the current window.

Just wondering if anyone knows a slick way to **open it up in a new browser window?**

Comment: have your tried adding `target="_blank"` to the link?

Comment: @max That did the trick. Nice one. Feel free to write it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: `disposition: :inline` is also key. Otherwise the file comes as a download

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `target` attribute on anchor (`<a>`) elements can be used to open linked pages in a new window.

```
<a href="#" target="_blank">I open in a new window.</a>
```

> _blank: Load the response into a new unnamed HTML4 window or HTML5 browsing context.
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a