# Ruby On Rails - Show pre-download page with a timer, initiate download in background once timer expires,then redirect to another view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have already looked at answers to this question [send_data - open file in new browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31466521/send-data-open-file-in-new-browser-window) but that do not solve my problem.

I have a website where user will click on a download button. Upon clicking the the button, he is to be taken to a page where I will show some information, along with a banner saying that download will begin in N seconds. Once the timer expires the file will be downloaded (not displayed). Then the current page has to be automatically redirected to another 'post download' page in my controller. I am encountering problem implementing this.

What I have already done:

I am using `send_data` from my controller to send the file as binary data to browser and ask the broswer to download it instead of displaying it.

```
send_data buffer, :filename => @organisation.id.to_s + '.key', :disposition => "attachment"
```

I am using `"target"="_blank"` to initiate download on a new page.

```
<a href="#" target="_blank">I open in a new window.</a>
```

Can you suggest how I can achieve the intended flow?

Comment: To begin with, when the user clicks the button, you redirect him to a page and to show the **timer** you can take a look at [this](https://github.com/jnbt/countdown). When the counter hits 0, trigger an event that make a call to the controller action where, you're initiating the download of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I achieved this.

You can not achieve this by using two controller actions alone. You need at least three controller actions and some client side Javascript.

Here is what you need to do.

1. Render a pre-download page where you show any ads or details or yet another 'Download Now' button.
2. With-in the pre-download page, create a timer in javascript. When the timer expires , using java script open the direct download link with target set as "_blank"

   ```
   window.open("https://example.com/direct_download_url" , "_blank");
   ```
3. Using java script, redirect the current page to a 'post-download' page.

   ```
   window.location.href = "https://www.example.com/after_download_page";
   ```
4. Use `send_data` with depostion as `"attachment"` in your controller action for direct download

   ```
   send_data buffer, :filename => "file_name", :disposition => "attachment"
   ```

Here is how the controller file would looks like.

```
class DownloadsController < ApplicationController

  def pre_download_page

  end

  def direct_download
     #Your logic here
     #.......
     send_data buffer, :filename => "file_name", :disposition => "attachment"
  end

  def after_download_page

  end        
end
```

Here is how View for pre_download_page would look like

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function startDirectDownload()
  {
     window.open("https://example.com/downloads/direct_download?file_id=12" , "_blank");
  }

  function redirectToAfterDownloadPage()
  {
     window.location.href = "https://www.example.com/downloads/after_download_page";
  }

  /*** If you want to start downloading after 10 seconds ***/
  setTimeout(function() {

     startDirectDownload();
     redirectToAfterDownloadPage();
  }, 10000);

  /** If you want the download to start immediately **/
  startDirectDownload();
  setTimeout(function() {
     redirectToAfterDownloadPage();
  },10000);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for taking the time!

In the mean time I resolved the issue in a simpler manner. Take a look:

***In my controller: ***

def generate_key

```
   ... LOGIC ...

send_data buffer, :filename => 'whatever.key', :disposition => "attachment", :type => 'text/plain'
```

end

***In my view:***

link_to 'Label', generate_key_organisation_path, target: "_blank"